# Not able to See Encyrpted Sent Mail via Java Program through Domino Sever

Tags: java, email, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, interop-domino

I am sending email through Domino Server by writing java mail sender program.
Previously I was using notes dll but now I have switched to iiop. Since then I am not able to see the content of my **sent Encrypted mail**. The recepients can read the mail very well its just me. But I should be able to see my sent Encrypted mail.

When I send email via Lotus Notes client then it works.
Did I forget to set anything in code or what?

Code used is below:

```
 public boolean sendMail(boolean schedule, String subject, String body, List<String> recipients, boolean doEncryt, boolean html, List<Binary> binaries, List<String> cc, List<String> bcc, List<String> replyTo)
    {

        String errorTxt = "";

        boolean diiop = true;
        try 
        { 
            Session session = null;
            // if (diiop)
            try {
                session = NotesFactory.createSession(NOTESMAILSERVER,"SOMEID",NOTESIDPW);
                diiop = true;
            }
            // else
            catch (Exception exc){
                NotesThread.sinitThread();
                session = NotesFactory.createSession();
                Registration lRegistration = session.createRegistration();
                lRegistration.switchToID(ResourceHelper.findResource(NOTESIDPATH).getFile().getAbsolutePath(), NOTESIDPW);
                diiop = false;
            }


            DbDirectory dir = session.getDbDirectory(NOTESMAILSERVER);
            Database    lDb = dir.openMailDatabase();

            session.setConvertMime(true);
            session.setConvertMIME(true);
            Document lDoc = lDb.createDocument();

            lDoc.replaceItemValue("Form"    ,"Memo");

            //set receip email addresses
            fillAdressItem(lDoc, recipients, "SendTo");
            fillAdressItem(lDoc, cc, "CopyTo");
            fillAdressItem(lDoc, bcc, "BlindCopyTo");

            //set subject
            lDoc.replaceItemValue("Subject" , subject);

            //set sender
            lDoc.replaceItemValue("From", this.FROM);
            lDoc.replaceItemValue("Principal", this.FROM);

            //prepare body text
            prepareRichTextBody(body, html, session, lDoc);

            //handle attachments
            RichTextItem lAttachmentItem = lDoc.createRichTextItem("attachments");

            if(binaries != null)
            {
                for(Binary binary : binaries)
                {

                    File tempFile = new File(getTempFolder(),binary.getName());
                    IOUtils.copyLarge(binary.getDataInputStream(), new FileOutputStream(tempFile));

                    lAttachmentItem.embedObject(EmbeddedObject.EMBED_ATTACHMENT, "", tempFile.getPath(), tempFile.getName());

                    tempFile.delete();
                }
            }

            //save if aSaveOnSend is true
            lDoc.setSaveMessageOnSend(true);

            //encrypt document if requested            
            if(doEncryt)
            {
                lDoc.setEncryptOnSend(true);
                lDoc.encrypt();
            }

            //send mail
            lDoc.send();

            return(true);
        } 
        catch(Throwable lE) 
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            if (!diiop) NotesThread.stermThread();
        }

    }
```

Kindly let me know what I am missing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling both lDoc.setEncryptOnSend(true) and lDoc.encrypt(). The encrypt() method is normally used with setEncryptionKeys() to do secret key encryption. Email uses public key encryption.

The help for the encrypt() method states

> Since mail encryption works differently, don't use this method if you
>   want to mail an encrypted document. Instead, set the EncryptOnSend
>   property to True, and use the Send method.

Try getting rid of the call to lDoc.encrypt(). My guess is that by calling it, you're changing something in the internal state of the document (maybe creating an empty SecretEncryptionKeys item) that is messing things up while saving your copy of the Sent message.

Comment: Thanks @Richard I will check this tomorrow and let you know whether that works. Hopefully it does. Thanks for the hint :)

Comment: Doing so made even Email delegates to read encrypted mail which shouldn't be the case?Email delegates should only see sender details, subject but NOT THE BODY. So is there anything else that needs to be done?

Comment: Encryption of saved email is normally under control of a user option. In Notes 9, that would be on the Mail tab of the User Security dialog - a checkbox labeled "Encrypt saved copy of mail that you send".  This setting applies to all messages sent by the user, so if your objective is to encrypt the saved copy for all users regardless of the setting, then I'm not sure how to proceed. IIRC, it's the router that saves the sent copy, not your code,

Comment: One thing that might be worth trying is creating a PublicEncryptionKeys item and adding the sender's name in canonical (CN=...) form to it.

Comment: I am sending email via java program, So I don't think I need to do anything in the Notes Client. What I think I am missing something programmatically. Also is there something special that needs to be done if IIOP is used(which is my case)? I didn't get canonical (CN=...) thing, What is that and what and where I need to use that in code?

Comment: Some settings that you make in the client are stored in the user's mail/calendar profile and are respected by APIs and/or by the router on the server, so I think it actually is possible that changing the client setting would solve your problem. I don't think you need to do anything special becuase of IIOP, but I could be wrong about that. Re canonical format, I was referring to the PublicEncyptionKeys item, which is a Names field, and the canonical storage format for name fields looks like this: "CN=Richard Schwartz/OU=Engineering/O=MyCompany" (simlar to an LDAP DN, but not quite the same).